# How to input Abs[x] as |x|?

Tags: formatting, keyboard

I could swear that I have seen *Mathematica* expressions (in something like `InputForm` or `FullForm`, as opposed to `TraditionalForm`) where something *looking* very much like `|x|` is equivalent to `Abs[x]`, but I can't find anything about it in the docs.  Am I imagining things?

---

**Non-answers**

Using the vertical bar character (i.e. "|") available in any standard US keyboard won't work.  E.g. if one tries to evaluate the expression

```
|-1|
```

...*Mathematica* emits an error:

```
Syntax::tsntxi: "|-1|" is incomplete; more input is needed.
```

If, on the other hand, the expression that results from typing

```
\[LeftBracketingBar]-1\[RightBracketingBar]
```

evaluates to itself, not to `1`.